# Auto increment starting at different offset for existing rows

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, database-migration

I have two tables existing_students and old_students with data in them, now i want to introduce a new auto increment column say alumni_number and assign a number to all students(old and existing). First i start with old_students table say having 100 rows

```
ALTER TABLE OLD_STUDENTS ADD ALUMNI_NUMBER INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD index (ALUMNI_NUMBER);
```

it will assign 1 to 100 to each row....now i want to start the count from 101 in existing_students....is it possible to allocated number 101,102 ...automatically to rows in existing_students table?
Any pointers will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Demo:

```
mysql> select * from mytable;
+----------+
| name     |
+----------+
| Harry    |
| Ron      |
| Hermione |
+----------+

mysql> alter table mytable 
  add column id int unsigned not null auto_increment, 
  add key (id), 
  auto_increment=101;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----------+-----+
| name     | id  |
+----------+-----+
| Harry    | 101 |
| Ron      | 102 |
| Hermione | 103 |
+----------+-----+
```